Tool for finding bitcoin transactions with specific characteristics
Just wondering if exists a tool to find transactions with certain parameters/characteristics; for example, a transaction with a SIGHASH ALL|ANYONECANPAY input and no OP_RETURN outputs.

If you run your own node and know how to write command-line shell scripts then you can build your own: just use the RPC to request blocks in JSON format and use a tool like jq to filter on the TX fields you're interested in and put the operation into a loop across the block range you're interested in.
Example of how to use RPC through bitcoin-cli command-line tool can be found here: Is it possible to get bitcoin address from Jan 2010 that still has balance and never send out transactions?
